# Webscrape in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm new to webscraping and trying to webscrape the information from this website  https://kfcsg.cognizantorderserv.com/nutrition-allergen . Ideally, I want to consolidate all the KFC food and their nutrition information into 1 table where I can then compare the nutrition info of the different food items. So the table should consists of [columns: "Food", "Servings (g)", "Energy (kcal)", "Protein (g)", "Total Fat (g)", "Saturated fat (g)", "Carbohydrate (g)", "Sodium (mg)"] and their respective strings/values seen in the website.

I have incorporated selenium as suggested.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\...\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://kfcsg.cognizantorderserv.com/nutrition-allergen')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

tr = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in tr:
    cols = row.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'align-middle ng-binding'})
    print(cols)
```

Snippet of results after `print(cols)`:

```
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">Original Recipe Chicken Drum</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">71</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">178</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">15.4</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">9.8</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">4.4</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">7</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">0</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">389</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">Original Recipe Keel</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">141</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">396</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">31.7</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">23.1</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">10.4</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">15.4</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">1</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">953</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">Original Recipe Rib</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">152</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">415</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">30.7</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">24.9</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">11.4</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">16.9</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">1.2</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">1107</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">Original Recipe Thigh</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">129</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">343</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">23.3</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">21.5</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">8.9</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">14.1</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">0.9</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">749</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">Original Recipe Wing</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">90</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">259</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">20.9</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">15.8</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">6.8</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">8.6</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">0</td>, <td class="align-middle ng-binding">539</td>]
[]
[]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">71</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">178</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">15.4</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">9.8</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">4.4</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">7</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">389</td>]
[]
[]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">141</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">396</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">31.7</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">23.1</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">10.4</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">15.4</td>]
[<td class="align-middle ng-binding">953</td>]
```

So then I want to append the results to a dataframe but I ran into the following error.

```
tr = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in tr:
    cols = row.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'align-middle ng-binding'})
    food = cols[0].text
    serving = cols[1].text
    energy = cols[2].text
    protein = cols[3].text
    fat = cols[4].text
    satfat = cols[5].text
    carb = cols[6].text
    sodium = cols[7].text

    # Finally we append the data of each row to the table
    kfc_data = kfc_data.append({"Food": food, "Servings (g)": serving, "Energy (kcal)": energy, "Protein (g)": protein, "Total Fat (g)": fat, "Saturated fat (g)": satfat, "Carbohydrate (g)": carb, "Sodium (mg)": sodium}, ignore_index=True)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...\Test.py", line 30, in <module>
    food = cols[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I append the lists that I've gotten after printing(cols) without any errors?

**Final Update: I used try: and except: to handle the error. Managed to get the data that I want in the table format I sought.**

Comment: You probably need selenium for this one.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, you need to use Selenium. Why? Because without JavaScript your page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see it's hard to scrape. So use Selenium (or Playwright).